# My code is giving different outputs in different platforms

Tags: c++, string.h

First of all this is the code.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string.h>

using namespace std;

int main() {

    char word[20];
    char blank[20];
    char guess[1];
    char *pch;
    int life=6;

    cout<<"Enter your word : ";
    cin>>word;

    for(unsigned int i=0;i<strlen(word);i++){

        blank[i]='_';

    }

    cout<<blank<<endl;

    while(blank != word && life >= 0){

        if(strcmp(word,blank) == 0){

            cout<<"Congratulations you found the word. :)";
            break;
        }


        if(life == 0)break;

        cout<<"Your guess :";
        cin>>guess[0];

        pch=strchr(word,int(guess[0]));

        if(pch == NULL){

        cout<<"Your guess is wrong try again."<<endl;
        cout<<life<<endl;

        }

        else if(pch != NULL){

            while (pch!=NULL){
                blank[pch-word]=guess[0];
                pch=strchr(pch+1,int(guess[0]));
            }

            cout<<blank<<endl;
            cout<<life<<endl;

            life++;

        }

        --life;

    }

    if(life == 0)cout<<"Sadly you couldn't find the word. :(";

    return 0;
}
```

So im tring to write a hangman code. I manage to work this really bad written code in eclipse. Its somewhat gets the job done but when try to implement it to codeblocks seems like this part of the program doesn't work properly.

```
    for(unsigned int i=0;i<strlen(word);i++){

        blank[i]='_';

    }

    cout<<blank<<endl;
```

Codeblocks gives me weird outputs like this :

```
Enter your word : ankara
______B
Your guess ::
```

or this :

```
Enter your word : adana
_____rB
Your guess :
```

Does anyone have any idea why codeblocks giving me different outputs ?
By the way excuse my bad english.

Comment: If your array is declared as `char blank[20]` then you can only put 19 underscores in there because you also need a terminating null for it to be a valid C string.

Comment: Use `std::string`... you're programming C++, not C

Comment: @jarmod thank you for your answer but im already filling less then 19 blanks you can see it in the outputs that i got the word "ankara" is 6 letters long my problem is codeblocks putting this random 'B' character after the blanks for example in "ankara" input

Comment: string.h is a C header. Use either cstring or string. You have to terminate your cstring with a `'\0'`

Comment: You are failing to create valid strings. They need a null terminator. Your `blank[20]` string is not initialized so it has random contents. Then you place 6 underscores in it, but the 7th character (in fact 7 through 20) were never initialized. Either `strcpy(blank, word)` before updating `blank` with underscores, or explicitly write a null terminator after the underscores.

Comment: @OğuzhanGüvercin -- Nowhere do you null-terminate your char arrays.  So expect odd things to occur.  Thus you are at mercy of wherever the null character happens to be placed in memory.  That's why you're getting differing behavior.

Comment: What is `kelime`?

Comment: @ThomasSablik sorry i translated the code before uploading in here. "kelime" means "word  i edited after you mentioned.

Comment: @jarmodandPaulMcKenzie thank you for your answers. So if i don't put null myself program puts it randomly. I got it thank you guys so much .I appreciate the efforts.

Comment: What is `can` ?

Comment: Not sure what your intention is with testing `blank != word` but it isn't correct, or useful.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use C++ strings instead of cstrings

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>

using namespace std;

int main() {
    std::string word;
    char guess;
    char *pch;
    int life=6;

    cout<<"Enter your word : ";
    cin>>word;
    std::string blank(word.size(), '_');

    cout<<blank<<endl;

    while(blank != word && can >= 0){

        if(word == blan){

            cout<<"Congratulations you found the word. :)";
            break;
        }


        if(life == 0)break;

        cout<<"Your guess :";
        cin>>guess;

        pch=strchr(word.c_str(),int(guess));

        if(pch == NULL){

        cout<<"Your guess is wrong try again."<<endl;
        cout<<life<<endl;

        }

        else if(pch != NULL){

            while (pch!=NULL){
                blank[pch-word.c_str()]=guess;
                pch=strchr(pch+1,int(guess));
            }

            cout<<blank<<endl;
            cout<<life<<endl;

            life++;
        }
        --life;
    }
    if(can == 0)cout<<"Sadly you couldn't find the word. :(";

    return 0;
}
```